# basic bit field C

Tags: c, field, bit

I don't know why this code works. it supposed to print out every student which follows chem. but why does a number for instance 21&4(student 123001) evaluate to true while a number like 49&4(123008) doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is due to bit operation AND.

In binary

```
49 is 110001 
 4 is 000100
 & =  000000
```

So it evaluates to `false`

wheras

```
21 is 10101
 4 is 00100
 & =  00100
```

So you get a non-zero result which is true.